# Cannot resolve module "firebase" from 'firebase.js' : Firebase could not be found within the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm having issues getting firebase into this project and I'm really not sure what is going wrong? All the firebase code (except the project-specific config code) is exactly the same as another (working) project...

I'm Using react-native with expo and have the FB database as a web project.

I Initialize the database in a file called firebase.js on the root level of the project, it's sitting right next to app.js. Database doesn't have security rules yet so I removed some of the info but its what you would expect for an api key.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "removed for post",
    authDomain: "removed for post",
    databaseURL: "removed for post",
    projectId: "goalsdev-7eb67",
    storageBucket: "goalsdev-7eb67.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "362368452051",
    appId: "removed for post",
    measurementId: "G-CNRGY3FTLE"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

Then I try and use it like so...

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

this is in ***/screens/signUpFinal***, have also tried importing as 'firebase.js', '../firebase' and '../firebase.js'

package.json is:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^9.2.3",
    ...
...
```

Answer (score 13):

First run

```
npm install --save firebase
```

And instead of this:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase"
```

Use this:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#node.js-apps

And also this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

To this:

```
import firebase from '../firebase'
```

And remove `@react-native-firebase` libraries because they won't work with expo.

Comment: Hey Kareem! I touched on this a little bit in the initial question but I did try this and am still getting the same error. Doing "./" is actually still pointing inside the screen folder and not on the root of the project. Both that and "../" didn't work.

Comment: I got it, I tried doing what you said above and it through the error that firebase/app wasn't in the project. I had a @react-native-firebase/app installed. I went back and ran npm install firebase and that fixed it. I tried replacing 'firebase' import with the 'react-native-firebase/app' awhile ago and was getting the same error. Guess that's why i didn't think of this sooner. either way thanks for the help! Got it fixed.

Comment: Glad I could help , however if you are using expo you can't use all the features of firebase you can use the web version only which you are using now, for more information: https://rnfirebase.io/#expo
https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-firebase/#usage-with-expo

Answer (score 7):

I found that this is the best/easiest way to use in React.js with no problem ....you can try to import like this ( "firebase": "^9.6.1",) :

```
        import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
        import 'firebase/compat/auth';
        import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

create your configfile .....

```
    const firebaseConfig = { your config data ...};
```

and then you can use it in this way without any annoying error :

```
    const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    const db = firebaseApp.firestore();

    const auth = firebase.auth();

    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
```

I hope it can help for others who have the same problem I had

Answer (score 3):

The last time I had to install firebase was over 6 months ago and that was "firebase": "^8.6.2". The configuration looked something like;

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/messaging';
import 'firebase/analytics';
import {
API_KEY,
AUTH_DOMAIN,
DATABASE_URL,
PROJECT_ID,
STORAGE_BUCKET,
MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
APP_ID,
MEASUREMENT_ID,
MESSAGING_VAPID_KEY,
} from '../config';

const config = {
 apiKey: API_KEY,
 authDomain: AUTH_DOMAIN,
 databaseURL: DATABASE_URL,
 projectId: PROJECT_ID,
 storageBucket: STORAGE_BUCKET,
 messagingSenderId: MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
 appId: APP_ID,
 measurementId: MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase App with Configurations
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Setup Firestore
const analytics = firebase.analytics();
const database = firebase.firestore();
const storage = firebase.storage();

// Setup push messaging
let messaging = null;
if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
  messaging = firebase.messaging();
  messaging.usePublicVapidKey(MESSAGING_VAPID_KEY);
}

export {
  firebase, storage, messaging, analytics, config, database as default,
};
```

As of the time of posting this, firebase is at v9 and a lot has changed. Kindly refer to the official doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

for help with setting up firebase on a project.

Answer (score 3):

Google has updated Firebase from version 8 to modular Web SDK. For this reason if you are using `firebase@>9.0.0` then it will be a bit different.
In the `firebase.js` file you need to import firebase like this.

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
```

So a sample of your `firebase.js` will look like this

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import { FIREBASE_CONFIG } from "./constants/firebase";
import "firebase/compat/storage";

firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
export const storage = firebase.storage();
export default firebase;
```

Here `FIREBASE_CONFIG` is your firebase configuration

As shown in the example use this `storage` object in other files.
As here I used this `storage` to other functions and worked on its functionalities like upload files etc.

I haven't tried with other services like authentication but at least firebase-storage service worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`cd src` from project file inside src do `npm install firebase`,I was facing same issue, but this solution sorted my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Couple days ago I found that my Codesandbox pet project crashed with kinda this error.

I leave only this import

```
import firebase from "firebase";
```

instead of

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

and

```
import "firebase/auth";
```

and it thankfully worked! Hope it will help.